# First UIButton fires another UIbutton event of same view

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, target-action

i have create two UIButton in swift and added action programmatically. When i try to click on the first button both button action are fired. But when i click on the second button none of the events are firing.

```
var btnSort = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(2, 74, 140, 26))
btnSort.setTitle("SORT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btnSort.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
btnSort.tag=10
btnSort.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showSortTbl:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(btnSort)



var btnFilter = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(140+16+2, 74, 140, 26))
btnFilter.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
btnFilter.tag=11
btnFilter.setTitle("FILTER", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btnSort.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showFilterTbl:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(btnFilter)



func showSortTbl(sender: UIButton){
    var btnSendTag :UIButton = sender
    if(btnSendTag.tag == 10){

println("show sort")

    }

}


func showFilterTbl(sender: UIButton){

    var btnSendTag :UIButton = sender
    if(btnSendTag.tag == 11){

        println("show filter")

    }

}
```

Comment: You are adding both actions to same button i.e btnSort.

Comment: "copy paste" error. `btnSort`s

Comment: yah, first i created action for a button and for another while copying i forgot to change the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
btnSort.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showFilterTbl:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

to

```
btnFilter.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showFilterTbl:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: oops ..that simple mistake.. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @anishparajuli You should mark this as your answer then.